# Is there a lucene.net (C#) method to remove stop words?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Something along the lines of Lucene.RemoveStopwords(string); ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove common english words strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532889/remove-common-english-words-strategy)

Answer (score 1):

There is the `StopFilter` class, which is included in the `TokenStream` chain of the `StandardAnalyzer` if that is what you use.

It resides in the `Lucene.Net.Analysis` namespace.